# Finding local coordinates in linear intervals

Tags: r, dplyr, intervals, genomicranges

I have a `data.frame` with `interval` coordinates (of exons and coding-sequence exons, of gene transcripts):

```
df <- data.frame(seqnames=rep("chr1",24),
                 start=c(3670552,3670552,3421702,3421702,3214482,3216025,4807823,4807914,4808455,4808455,4828584,4828584,4830268,4830268,4832311,4832311,4837001,4837001,4839387,4839387,4840956,4840956,4844963,4844963),
                 end=c(3671498,3671348,3421901,3421901,3216968,3216968,4807982,4807982,4808486,4808486,4828649,4828649,4830315,4830315,4832381,4832381,4837074,4837074,4839488,4839488,4841132,4841132,4846739,4845013),
                 strand=c(rep("-",6),rep("+",18)),
                 exon_number=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9),
                 width=c(947,797,200,200,2487,944,160,69,32,32,66,66,48,48,71,71,74,74,102,102,177,177,1777,51),
                 type=c('exon','CDS','exon','CDS','exon','CDS','exon','CDS','exon','CDS','exon','CDS','exon','CDS','exon','CDS','exon','CDS','exon','CDS','exon','CDS','exon','CDS'),
                 #exon_number=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8),
                 transcript_id=c(rep("a",6),rep("b",18)),stringsAsFactors = F)

> head(df)
  seqnames   start     end strand exon_number width type transcript_id
1     chr1 3670552 3671498      -           1   947 exon             a
2     chr1 3670552 3671348      -           1   797  CDS             a
3     chr1 3421702 3421901      -           2   200 exon             a
4     chr1 3421702 3421901      -           2   200  CDS             a
5     chr1 3214482 3216968      -           3  2487 exon             a
6     chr1 3216025 3216968      -           3   944  CDS             a
```

he organization is as follows:

Each `transcript_id` is made up of a set of `exon`s, which are linear intervals along `seqnames` (which are chromosomes), defined by `start` and `end`. These `exon`s have an orientation/directionality which depends on `strand` (which is identical for all `exon`s of each `transcript_id`): if `strand == "-"` then actually `end` is the first position of the exon and `start` is its last position. If the `strand == "+"` then `start` and `end` are the first and last positions, respectively.

The `CDS` lines are a subset the `exon`s. Usually, leave the first and last few `exon`s in each `transcript_id`, each `exon` has an identical `CDS` interval (in terms of the coordinates). However, the exceptions are:

1. The `CDS` intervals are a subset of the `exon`s, meaning they may start and/or end within an `exon`(s). It can be that the first position of the first `CDS` interval is after that of the closest `exon`, and/or the last position of the last `CDS` interval is before that of the closest `exon`. It's also possible that a `transcript_id` will have a single `exon` (and therefore a single `CDS`) meeting these definitions.
2. `transcript_id`'s where all `exon`s have identical `CDS` intervals
3. `transcript_id`'s where the `exon`s that do not have identical `CDS` intervals are only the first few ones
4. `transcript_id`'s where the `exon`s that do not have identical `CDS` intervals are only the last few ones

I'm looking for a fast `function` that will return the local coordinates of the `CDS` relative to the coordinates of the `transcript_id` whose `exon`s have been combined. Essentially, `start` in the resulting `data.frame` is the sum of `exon` interval widths up to the first `CDS` interval + `start` of the first `CDS` - `start` of the `exon` it's a subset of (or `end` if `strand == "-"`) and `end` is `CDS` `start` +  sum of `CDS` widths.

Here's what I'm doing so far but it's slow:

```
res.df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(unique(df$transcript_id),function(t){
  transcript.df <- df %>% dplyr::filter(transcript_id == t)
  up.cds.df <- dplyr::filter(transcript.df,type == "exon",exon_number < min(dplyr::filter(transcript.df,type == "CDS")$exon_number))
  down.cds.df <- dplyr::filter(transcript.df,type == "exon",exon_number > max(dplyr::filter(transcript.df,type == "CDS")$exon_number))
  cds.df <- dplyr::filter(transcript.df,exon_number >= min(dplyr::filter(transcript.df,type == "CDS")$exon_number,exon_number <= max(dplyr::filter(transcript.df,type == "CDS")$exon_number)))
  first.cds.exon.number <- (cds.df %>% dplyr::filter(type == "CDS") %>% dplyr::filter(exon_number == min(exon_number)))$exon_number
  if(transcript.df$strand[1] == "+"){
    cds.start <- dplyr::filter(cds.df,type == "CDS",exon_number == first.cds.exon.number)$start-dplyr::filter(cds.df,type == "exon",exon_number == first.cds.exon.number)$start+1+sum(up.utr.df$width)
  } else{
    cds.start <- dplyr::filter(cds.df,type == "exon",exon_number == first.cds.exon.number)$end-dplyr::filter(cds.df,type == "CDS",exon_number == first.cds.exon.number)$end+1+sum(up.utr.df$width)
  }
  return(data.frame(transcript_id=t,start=cds.start,end=cds.start+sum(dplyr::filter(cds.df,type == "CDS")$width),stringsAsFactors = F))
}))


> res.df
  transcript_id start  end
1             a   151 2092
2             b    92  782
```

Any advice on how to speed it up? possible using `dplyr`